# ${device} in Freemarker template ( liferay version 7.0 and 7.4) does not return device data

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I am trying to get data from freemarker about the kind of device I use and the browser  ,
There is ${device} in Freemarker template , but it does not return data, just it returns unknown.

This is what I get :

```
{brand=unknown, browser=unknown, browserVersion=unknown, model=unknown, os=unknown, osVersion=unknown, pointingMethod=unknown, qwertyKeyboard=true, screenPhysicalSize={height=-1.0, width=-1.0}, screenResolution={height=-1.0, width=-1.0}, tablet=false}
```

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 1):

For Liferay DXP the Device detection capabilities allowing the Freemarker call `${device}` to function will work after the installation of the Liferay Mobile Device Detection Lite (LMDD), unfortunately, this option is only available with EE-version.

Another option is you will have to create Mobile Device Rules for each one of them: https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028819552-Mobile-Device-Rules

With mobile device rules, you can alter what gets displayed based on the device being used to access Liferay DXP.

For example: create a group for all Android devices; if Liferay detects an Android device, it can redirect the visitor to a mobile-friendly page.

Hope this helps.